# CSS rgba in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, background, opacity, rgba

I have box with `RGBa` opacity background. It works in all browsers except IE. I tried it on IE 8. IE show page without background (rgba color). I tried ms filter:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#50990000,endColorstr=#50990000);
```

zoom: 1; and -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";  it do not work. This is my background code:

`background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg,rgba(238,242,243,0.65) 30.57%,rgba(239,239,239,0.89) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(238,242,243,0.65) 30.57%,rgba(239,239,239,0.89) 100%);`

and full code of box:

```
   .box1 {
    height: 1100px;
    width: 800px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 20px 20px 20px #CCC;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 20px 20px 20px #CCC;
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 20px #CCC;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg,rgba(238,242,243,0.65) 30.57%,rgba(239,239,239,0.89) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(238,242,243,0.65) 30.57%,rgba(239,239,239,0.89) 100%);}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for IE8 to work with the CSS RGBa property, you need to place the IE8 syntax at the beginning of your RGBa entries; before any webkit or standards-compliant entries:

```
/* IE8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#50990000,endColorstr=#50990000)";

/* Other Browsers */
-webkit-linear-gradient(270deg,rgba(238,242,243,0.65) 30.57%,rgba(239,239,239,0.89) 100%);

linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(238,242,243,0.65) 30.57%,rgba(239,239,239,0.89) 100%);

/* IE9+ */
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#50990000,endColorstr=#50990000);
```

Comment: It do not work for me. It work for other browsers but IE8 still show page without background.

Comment: @user3289606 you also need to set `background: transparent;` I believe.

Comment: i define   background: transparent; beginning of RGBA entries but it still not work. I tried background-color: transparent; too. I do not have idea where is the problem.